# Is there any way to skip to next song while repeat one is enabled in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, mac

Let's suppose that I'm playing an album with several songs.

If I enable repeat>one, the same song will be played after the song is over.

However, while that option is enabled, pressing next song on the touch bar does not move on to next song - it just start over with the same song.

If I remember correctly, this broken repeat one functionality was introduced at iTunes 11. (i.e. on iTunes 10.x when I press next song button it played different song)

Is there any way to change this behavior?